# Storing dynamic fetched data while preserving types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am quite new to typescript and I am not sure if this is achievable or not.

Basically, I have some fetched data with known types (some queries to database) and I want to store them in a **predefined** variable so I can pass it around (a context in my use case). However, the data type changes base on the query parameters. I am storing the data inside the variable with type any but the intellisense would be lost.

```ts
// file A.ts
export const someContext : { fetchedData: any } = { fetchedData: null }
```

```ts
// file B.ts
import { someContext } from "A"
...
const data = await fetchData("some api and queries")
// data can be {id: string, posts: number} or {id: string, lastLogin: Date} etc
// but the type is known
someContext.fetchedData = data; // there is no intellisense for fetchedData
```

My question is can I store the data in only one variable while preserving type intellisense.

One solution I thought of is to create a type of all possible fields of the fetched data (based on the database structure), and mark every field as optional but this is quite complicated and I need to update it everytime I change the db structure and I want to know if there is a way **without statically setting the types**. Ideally, I would want it to work with nested objects as well.

```ts
type fetchedDataTypes = {
    id?: number; // statically setting types
    lastLogin?: Date;
    posts?: number;
    ...
}
const someContext : { fetchedData: fetchedDataTypes } = { fetchedData : {} }
```

**EDIT:**
For some more context, I am doing something similar to an API call from client to server, and the context is created from the server side and is passed around to different components that is run from the client side, so any data passed into it will persist and can be used across the whole app. The syntax is of course different base on the framework used, but one example similar is nextjs + tRPC, where the end-points for the api calls are typesafe, and I want to find a way to store the data from the api calls without losing the type intellisense, and also without statically setting the types in prior.

A minimal reproducible example using react [here](https://playcode.io/1568589).

Comment: Have you considered using [discriminated unions](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions)?

Comment: It works but I am trying to look for a solution that doesn't require statically typing out the fields' types beforehand, if possible.

Comment: Sam, please write al least 3 actual query examples with their returns to understand better 1) how return depends on query

Comment: Ah, the "return type is known" (fetchData returns typed value), nevermind then

Comment: "I am trying to look for a solution that doesn't require statically typing out the fields' types beforehand, if possible."  I don't understand what the alternative could possibly be; how would TS know the types otherwise?  Could you show some examples that demonstrate how you'd like to use this thing?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're asking for.

Comment: I am working on something that resembles nextjs + trpc where the api calls are typesafe, so you would know exactly the types you are getting from the fetch calls and I am trying to find a way to store the data from these api calls.

Comment: I would need to see a [mre] of intended usages, not just verbal descriptions (especially if said descriptions are allusions to third-party frameworks).  I still have no idea how you could hope to have IntelliSense without statically-defined types... indeed TS is a static type system added on top of JS; without static types, you have... just JavaScript?  Either I'm missing something or you're not understanding what TypeScript is. Anyway, I'll disengage unless I have something more constructive to say, possibly after another [edit] if it adds code examples.  Good luck either way!

Comment: I have added in sample codes which uses react for creating the context and doing the fetchData call. I will update the tag to contain react, though the same logic is applied to many frameworks.

Comment: make a `async function fetchGlobalData(){return {id:123,posts:7}}` then you'll get `type DataType = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof fetchGlobalData>>` you can place everywhere

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure what your `fetch()` call will return, you can use generics and [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to enforce certain return types that will give you intellisense. I'd recommend to define `FetchedData` as a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) instead of optional properties because there's a difference between a property of value `undefined` and a property that is not there at all.

However, you'll need to be really careful about that since you can trick yourself very easily. In the example below `fetchMock` will always return `{posts: 42}`. The return type will only be based on the generic argument.

```
type FetchedData =
  | {
      id: number;
    }
  | {
      posts: number;
    }
  | {
      lastLogin: Date;
    };

const someContext: {fetchedData: FetchedData | null} = {
  fetchedData: null
};

// mock
async function fetchMock<T extends FetchedData>(): Promise<T> {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve({posts: 42} as T))
  );
}

(async () => {
  someContext.fetchedData = await fetchMock<{id: number}>();
  console.log(someContext.fetchedData.id);

  someContext.fetchedData = await fetchMock<{posts: number}>();
  console.log(someContext.fetchedData.posts);

  someContext.fetchedData = await fetchMock<{lastLogin: Date}>();
  console.log(someContext.fetchedData.lastLogin);
})();
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYhwGMAWEAmARAhsTUC8AsAFBRQA+UA3sabVAJaoBcUAdgK4C2ARhAE4BuGrQC+witRJ0oYAPYBnYPJYce-IVNJipE4XQA2mRQBlZAc3qsWWYBA10RG4glmtFUebM4QAwq9sAHsAslABm8MhoNpgscIgoGNi4FBz6+iL4VMLh8VFJKuxpxI7ExAD0ZVCcsggA1sRGIKwIUKHszcD0rq0RSACyNbUAPAAqUBBBEKyo8rC9eTgAfAAUAJQsAAp8XvTyEKOLWVJ88Ox8rGwQAO5QWzt7yyee+gBu0HiLeh7wI-TesuxgMs1vhDk9ZK8IMtKHJFMooAAWABMGSMUBGq1WwlWGm0xGWjWaUBBHyOpE83j8rECwAAdDlIokcJlMFdMPRgD14gM6kNKIwCmo+CIVjjhC43BCILT9OZlhTfP4JnSGQlorTGGKiMIFVSafT5kzcHgoKz2ZzVTzhjCFEpBbxhaL7FAJc9pbKzPKvIrqcqDbkjbTYUotTrvXq-aqFsbTWyOVzkFa+YYTOZLNZsBARWtna6pTK5bqlUF-Yz1SngKYLKwtSJVjmgA)

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be

```
const data = await fetchData("some api and queries")
const someContext = { fetchedData: data }
```

If you need to create your object before, you may still use the type of data variable:

```
const someContext: { fetchedData: null | typeof data } = { fetchedData: null }
const data = await fetch("some api and queries")
someContext.fetchedData = data;
someContext.fetchedData.ok // boolean
// or
const someContext: { fetchedData?: typeof data } = { /** fetchedData: undefined */ }
const data = await fetch("some api and queries")
someContext.fetchedData = data;
someContext.fetchedData.ok // boolean
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the logic to create the context is completely separate from the data fetching. The context is created before the data fetching occurs.